# How can I use excel to autogenerate text with dropdowns

Tags: excel

I have an email that I need to write every month that I send out to 100+ recipients, and each email uses the same format with minor changes depending on the project. [Please see this photo for a better idea of what I mean, it has been modified to post but this is the general idea.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzuNF.png) All of the highlighted fields change.

I am looking for a way to generate it by selecting the options in drop-downs at the beginning of the sheet. I'm currently filling out the template manually for each email and it leaves a lot of room for error. I would like to enter the project, date, department etc. once and have it fill it out in French and English throughout the document. Ideally, it would also automatically fill out the to and cc fields for each project. I would then copy the subject, to, cc, and body of the message into Outlook once Excel generates it.

I have tried googling this but I am likely not using the right language to find the info I need. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have Outlook or Word? You could set this up with a Mail-Merge.

Comment: I use both. Using mail merge, would I be able to set up this template for others to use as well?

Comment: Yeah - search around for "mail merge", i.e. [How to Mail Merge](http://www.statelibraryofiowa.org/ld/q-s/silo/e-mail/outlook/email-merge), or [this, from Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-mail-merge-to-send-bulk-email-messages-0f123521-20ce-4aa8-8b62-ac211dedefa4).